# How to attach invoice pdf on invoice record in communication tab using suitescript 2.0?

Tags: pdf-generation, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, invoice

I have customized invoice advanced pdf. now I want to attach this pdf to invoice record in the communication tab and send email to the customer when invoice record is created. Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the advanced PDF template is set as default template on the invoice form that you are using, then you can use render.transaction(options) function from the N/render module. This will give you the PDF of the invoice. Use this PDF as an attachment with the email.send function from N/email module.

Use options.relatedRecords property to attach the email on the record.

Source: NetSuite technical consultant for 8 years now + NS docs